# Error coming when using the state value in react using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In one of the codes in react documentation, the value defined in this.state is used in render() as

```
{this.state.name}
```

But when I implement that react code using typescript, it is giving error as:-

```
Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
```

The code in the typescript is:-

```
import * as React from "react";
class App2 extends React.Component{
    constructor(props:any)
    {
        super(props)
         this.state = {
            age : 0,
            name : "rohit"
        };
    }

    public render()
    {
        return(
                <h1>
                    {this.state.name}
                </h1>
        )
    }
}
export default App2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Typescript you must provide types for props you accept and state of your class, so you shouldn't derive from plain `React.Component` (which defaults to `React.Component<{}, {}>` but instead declare template parameter to prop / state types you desire.

Stg like this should work for your case:

```
interface MyProps {
    something?: string;
}
interface MyState {
    age: 0;
    name: string;
}
class App2 extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
```

```